# How to create an sql query with dynamic filters in WHERE clause

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I'm currently on aws lambda/node js and my database is configured with rds/auroradb which uses the general mysql syntax. I have a frontend which has a table with multiple filters with dropdowns/checkboxes/sorting and more for which I'm trying to create a dynamic sql query which implements these filters/conditions in the WHERE clause of my query. What I'm looking for is a library that handles this for me easily.
What I've tried so far is a custom function that handles this for me. But this is causing a lot of issues and seems like an unreliable way to build queries dynamically.

```
const buildPatientQuery = (data) => {
  const queryBase = 'SELECT * FROM (patient as p JOIN patient_score as s ON p.patient_id=s.patient_id)';
  const { filters, sortBy } = data;
  let filterQuery = "WHERE";

  //Build query for dropdown and checkbox filters
  if (filters.length) {
    filters.map(item => {
      const { checkboxSelected, dropdownSelected, qf, fromToMode, individual, from, to, key } = item;
      if (qf) {
        console.log('Quick filter');
      }
      else {
        if (checkboxSelected) {
          if (queried) {
            console.log('Checkbox filter - queried');
          }
          else {
            console.log('Checkbox filter - not queried');
          }
        }
        else if (dropdownSelected) {
          //Check if range
          if (fromToMode) {
            filterQuery = `${filterQuery} AND ${key} BETWEEN ${from} AND ${to}`;         
          }
          //Check if individual item
          else if (individual) {
            filterQuery = `${filterQuery} AND ${key}='${direction}'`;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    filterQuery = ""
  }

  //Build query for sorting
  const { name, direction } = sortBy;
  const sortDirection = direction === "ascending" ? "ASC" : "DESC";
  filterQuery = `${filterQuery} ORDER BY ${name} ${sortDirection}`;

  //Return final query build
  return queryBase + " " + filterQuery;
}

module.exports = buildPatientQuery;
```

Comment: `let filterQuery = "WHERE 1=1";`. Then concatenate all needed conditions with needed operator (`AND`). Do not forget a space char between the operator.

Comment: This will actually resolve a major issue which is AND being added directly after WHERE with how the function is set up. Adding 1=1 directly after AND will be a perfect solution. Thanks a lot for this. Another issue will probably be how to implement OR. For eg: WHERE (city = 'berlin' OR city = 'munich') AND so on

Comment: Use `AND city IN ('berlin', 'munich')` form.

Comment: @Akina do you know about sql injection attacks. I've been told to implement sanity check in order to prevent sql injection which can cause security risks. But I don't know where to begin with this.